# Taking checkbox checked value name dynamically using Jquery MVC3

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I have these views

view1

```
  @if (@Model.QuestionType == 3)
 {
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("SaveCheckbox", "GetQuestion", Model))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken() 
        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" id="@(Model.QuestionNo)_fld">
            <label class="select">@Model.QuestionText
            </label>
            <br />
            @foreach (var item in Model.Options)
            {
                if (@item.IsAnswer == true)
                {
                <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="selectedObjects" id="@(Model.QuestionNo)_@(item.OptionNumber)_chk" value="@item.OptionNumber" class="custom"  />
                }
                else
                {
                <input type="checkbox"  name="selectedObjects" id="@(Model.QuestionNo)_@(item.OptionNumber)_chk" value="@item.OptionNumber" class="custom"   />   
                }
                <label for="@(Model.QuestionNo)_@(item.OptionNumber)_chk">
                    @item.OptionText</label> 
            }
            <br />
        </fieldset>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" id="@(Model.QuestionNo)_chk" onclick="return SaveCheckBoxNew(this);" value="Next" />
        </p>
    }
</div>
  }

   @if (@Model.QuestionType == 4)
  {
   <div data-role="fieldcontain">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("SaveCheckBoxTextInput", "GetQuestion", Model))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken() 
        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" id="@(Model.QuestionNo)_fld">
            <label id="l3" for="select-choice-1" class="select">@Model.QuestionText
            </label>
            <br />
            @foreach (var item in Model.Options)
            {

                if (@item.IsAnswer == true)
                {
                    if (@item.OptionText == "Other")
                    {
                <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="selectedObjects" questionid="@Model.QuestionNo" other="true" id="@(Model.QuestionNo)_@(item.OptionNumber)_chk" value="@item.OptionNumber" onchange="selectCheckbox(this);" />
                <input type="text" value="@item.Answer" name="selectedObjects" id="@(Model.QuestionNo)_chktxt"/>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="selectedObjects" questionid="@Model.QuestionNo" other="false" id="@(Model.QuestionNo)_@(item.OptionNumber)_chk" value="@item.OptionNumber" onchange="selectCheckbox(this);" />
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (@item.OptionText == "Other")
                    {
                <input type="checkbox" name="selectedObjects" questionid="@Model.QuestionNo" other="true" id="@(Model.QuestionNo)_@(item.OptionNumber)_chk" value="@item.OptionNumber" onchange="selectCheckbox(this);" />
                <input type="text" name="selectedObjects" id="@(Model.QuestionNo)_chktxt" style="display: none;" />
                    }
                    else
                    {
                <input type="checkbox" name="selectedObjects" questionid="@Model.QuestionNo" other="false" id="@(Model.QuestionNo)_@(item.OptionNumber)_chk" value="@item.OptionNumber" onchange="selectCheckbox(this);" />
                    }
                }

                <label for="@(Model.QuestionNo)_@(item.OptionNumber)_chk">
                    @item.OptionText</label> 
            }
            <br />
        </fieldset>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" id="@(Model.QuestionNo)__chktxtinput" value="Next" onclick="return validateCheckBoxTextInput(this);" />
        </p>
    }
</div>
 }
```

I am rendering the same view based on question types.
So i have written separate javascripts like this for both:

For 1:

```
function SaveCheckBoxNew(button) {
    alert($('input:checkbox[name=selectedObjects]:checked').val());
}
```

For 2 :

```
function validateCheckBoxTextInput(button){
alert($('input:checkbox[name=selectedObjects]:checked').val());
}
```

So if I do not check any checkbox in the second view it is showing the same value as selected in the first view.

I have to get the null if any checkbox is not checked in the second why the selectednameobjects is not cleared.

How do I solve this?
Thanks in advance for your help .

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$(this).closest("input:checkbox[name=selectedObjects]:checked").val());
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if your syntax is correct. What I use for checkboxes is this:

```
$('#selectedObjects').is(':checked')
```

That usually works for me. Maybe the syntax is not the problem, but you could test this...

Comment: its returning the false always even though they are checked.